# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Query when trying to run EE Jar from Windows CMD?

Tags: java, netbeans, ejb, persistence

I wrote a Java Client Enterprise Application, and it works very good when i run it from Netbeans.

please notice that there is a query run on start up of the application which send a query to Entitybean.

the problem is when i try to run this `JAR` Application from windows `command line`, this error appear to me:

`java -jar Apps.jar`

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClas
sDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Query
        at Apps.Main.main(Main.java:75)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Query
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

I'm surprised! because it connected successfully between `EntityManger` and `Database`, so it used libraries of `javax.persistence`! .. so Why it don't see the library while trying to send a query?!

So how i solve this problem to run the application by command line any where? not from `Netbeans` only ?!

1. Notes:

   - Windows 8
   - JDK8
   - I Set `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` Variables on Windows

Thanks,

Comment: Sometimes NoClassDefFoundError means there was an error in the constructor or static initializer of the class being loaded.  Is the "1 more" giving more information?

Comment: i can't press 1 because the application exit after error.!

Comment: You're missing something in your class-path. Presumably you need to add some dependencies.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch while that seems really likely, its complaining about javax.persistance.Query, which has been part of java since 1.0. Thats not a 3rd party API. That confuses me...

Comment: @MarkW No it hasn't. It's part of Enterprise Edition Java, and an extension. It's been in since `Java Persistence 1.0` or May, 11 2006 according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Persistence_API).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Youre right, I misread the doc, persistance 1.0 in java EE. My bad.

Comment: Generally, a Java EE application client should not be run using `java -jar`.  Most (all?) Java EE containers, including GlassFish, have a special tool for running an application client.  In GlassFish's case, it would be something like `appclient -client Apps.jar`.  The appclient tool is in GlassFish's bin directory, where startserv, stopserv, and asadmin reside.

Comment: Hi, i think that the problem i have to set classpath for both of libraries of Javax and Eclipse, because i attached source of repository Javax, and the error disappeared, but another error appeared `Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named PerPU`, so i want to avoid including source codes of this libraries insde my `.jar` file , and want to add something to the command `java -jar` during running it, i tried to add `-cp` but no thing solved !?

Comment: @VGR You are great!... lol working fine now

Comment: I have a similar problem but my JAR simply don't have the path javax/persistence. Better you verify within the JAR also.